# "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use fire base in my android application to Make Authentication

1. I create the app then downloaded the JSON  File and Paste it into    app folder
2. I added  this to my build.gradle > Project

   ```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
3. add this apply to my build.gradle > app

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 24
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.example.mahmoud.loginwithfirebase"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 24
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {

       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

   but this error appeared [image]

[image]

4. this MainActivity.java

   ```
   package com.example.mahmoud.loginwithfirebase;

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: "this error appear to me" is not a very specific title. In the future you may want to consider making your titles a little more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'` to your build.gradle dependencies like here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup but instead of core use auth.

Comment: Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/mahmoud/AndroidStudioProjects/LoginWithFirebase/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Go to Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of the two libraries : Google Play Services and Google Repository. if it doesn't work, try to use firebase-auth:9.6.0 instead of 9.6.1 .